# Silverlight / F# Reading URL parameter

Tags: silverlight, f#

I have web pages in SL (xaml) that are backed by F# behind it.
I initially have the page to be a pop up window:

```
type SomePage(window : ChildWindow, id: int) as this =
inherit UriCanvasControl("/AssemblyName;component/somePage.xaml", "Some Page")
```

It works no problem as I initiated this way:

```
let someWindow = new ChildWindow()
someWindow.Content <- new SomePage(someWindow , id) // assume have id from somewhere
someWindow.Title <- "Some Page"
someWindow.Show()
```

Now, I want to change that page into its own page rather than some pop-up window. I've made the necessary adjustment in the xaml and fs of SomePage to work as a page. However, I am having trouble with passing in that "id" param (the window param is not necessary anymore).

Here's how I navigate:

```
let parent = this.Parent :?> Frame
parent.Navigate(new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/somePage.xaml?id=" + id, UriKind.Relative)) |> ignore
```

so I got the id in the url now, but how do I read it in?

The page is now;

```
type SomePage() as this =
    inherit UriUserControl("/AssemblyName;component/somePage.xaml", "Some Page")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt - You should be able to use the `NavigationContext.QueryString` property to get the parameter specified by the query string:

```
type SomePage() as this =
  inherit UriUserControl("/AssemblyName;component/somePage.xaml", "Some Page") 
  let id = 
    if not(this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id")) then 0
    else int (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.["id"])
  // .. the rest of the page
```

**EDIT** *The following would work only in WPF - Silverlight doesn't support the overload.*

Instead of calling `Navigate` with `Uri` as an argument, you can construct the page you want to navigate to (as a standard .NET object) and then call overload of `Navigate` that takes a page. Then you can easily specify any parameters you need as constructor arguments:

```
// Declaration of parameterized page
type SomePage(id) as this =
  inherit UriUserControl("/AssemblyName;component/somePage.xaml", "Some Page") 

// Code that navigates to SomePage page with 'id' as argument
let parent = this.Parent :?> Frame
let somePage = new SomePage(id)
parent.Navigate(somePage)
```

Comment: The above wont quite work because Navigate requires URI (compile time error). I can do the above, but with parent.Navigate(somePage.uri) - it wont get to compilation problem, but it does get to run time problem because navigate seem to try to use 0-param constructor

Comment: Can you override the constructor?

Comment: @akaphenom: You meant to have another constructor with no param? but that would mean when we Navigate we actually navigate through the no param page object, which mean I lose reference to the id

Comment: @tsOverflow: Ah, you're correct. This can be done only in standard WPF. I'm not sure what other options are available in Silverlight.... Maybe this forum post could help: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/131303/450208.aspx

Comment: @tsOverflow: I added another answer that should work on Silverlight.